# Google photos keeps crashing

Tags: photos, crashes, google-apps

My [google photos app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.photos) keeps crashing whenever I open it. Sometimes it crashes in the background. I tried some fixes like clearing data, reinstalling, deleting big video files, maintaining nearly 4GB space etc. None of these fixed. I also tried an old version of the app which previously was working fine, now that one is also crashing.

I have the latest app version. I am on stock rom of 6.0.1 android version. My device is Lenovo K6 Power.

Since it keeps my photos synced to google cloud, so I would like it fixed rather than any alternative.

---

My findings :

1. App crashes when media scan is started.
2. Every version of app is crashing.

Comment: Are you stock? On what device? Version numbers of the app, etc, would be useful, please update the original question. This often occurs when you have a custom ROM and have flashed Gapps, but they are not updating properly. Also, have you tried just uninstalling and reinstalling the app?

Comment: Check this out please https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/200709/google-photos-and-files-apps-on-google-pixel-2-is-giving-the-following-error-an

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By my search, I got some key points which are reasons for crashing Google Photos app.

- First is low space.
   In my case, I was not having such problems as my device has good space. But need at least 1GB to work.
- The second was a bad video file. 
  There is no way we can identify which one, but cleaning all videos after taking backup will help.
- The third one was a bad photo file. 
  It wasn't posted as answer till I [asked](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/photos/2Y1TcRjbOEw) on google product forums. Clearing all of the photos from device helped me to get my photos app and as well as my device working fluently. Now, I don't have any problem.

These are those points which can't be helped by clearing data, reinstalling or trying any old version. These are also independent of device or android version.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem every time I oppended the app it crashed and I found that if i oppened it with wifi off it worked just fine so it had something to be with the automatic back up, I went to settings and allowed Backups trough cellular data and It started backing up just fine, then I turned off that option, went back to Wifi and all worked just fine, My guess is that a particular video or photo that was beeing uploades caused the crash with wifi so once it was uploaded with the cellular data the crash was no longer there, hope it helps.

I Have a Pixel 2 XL with Oreo 8.1

Answer (score 0):

I found that Google photos was crashing for me because I had two folders with very large file size pictures (over 100MB), so I went into the file explorer and deleted those folders (completely off the phone, since I have backups) and that resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

in my case i can confirm that is a corrupted file, when gphoto try to upload it, go into troubles.

To find the file:
Set airplane mode
Open gphoto
On your avatar you will find a file in "waiting to sync"
Understand what file is and delete it (open image details)
Done!

I hope to help someone!